# Best way to organize Angular Component flow

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model `MyModel` that has several "phases" during its life cycle. Currently, I'm using an `enum` called `MyWorkflowComponentState` to handle which way the model is used by its consumers:

```
export enum MyWorkflowComponentState {
    Selecting, // Select "sub models"
    Editing, // Edit parent model
    Displaying,
    ...
}

@Component()
export class MyWorkflowComponent {
    myWorkflowComponentState = MyWorkflowComponentState;

    @Input()
    state: MyWorkflowComponentState;
    model: MyModel;
    ...
}

<div [ngSwitch]="state">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="myWorkflowComponentState.Selecting">
        <app-select [model]="model"> </app-select>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="myWorkflowComponentState.Editing">
        <app-edit [model]="model"> </app-edit>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="myWorkflowComponentState.Displaying">
        <app-display [model]="model"> </app-display>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

This makes for a pretty seamless flow through the different states of working with the model, however something about this feels dirty to me and I'm worried I might encounter issues later on. If this is considered bad practice or you all can see a major flaw in this design, can someone please offer an alternative method of handling this?

Clarification: the workflow component itself will be a sub component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using routing,that will give you more flexibility.
Refer this link for more information: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: What if the workflow component is going to be a sub view of another component?

Comment: Then the parent view will have the router-outlet and all the child components will be loaded inside the parent view